# Left Join on Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com API for Mobile application and I'm concerned about NoSQL database modeling.

**Context:**
I have classes `Establishment` and `User`, and I want my users to be able to Favorite an `Establishment`. But I can't change `Establishment` itself for this feature. So I save the reference into another place (JoinTable or User's attribute as an array).

**Problem:**
The problem is that my app gets Establishments paginated 10 by 10, and it must show user's favorite establishments first. But Establishment is not aware of user's like.

So, suppose we have a user with 3 establishments liked. How can I get in one request 10 establishments with the first 3 ones as my user's favorites ? P.S: The next request would return 10 more Establishments not liked by my user.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the proper solution:

-First of all create an Array column inside of User's class in Parse.com ; this column will be used to store all favourite Establishments. In this Array you can write all Establishment ids, like this (as Strings): [EstablishmentId0,EstablishmentId1,EstablishmentId2]

-When you do a query to get all Establishment, you will get an ArrayList, so compare each element with the current User Favourites Array by id. If some element matches with your Array ids, put it on the top of your list. So the result will be a list of 10 elements with your three favourites on the top of the list.

Hope it helps!
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

For a long term solution, I think you should create another class named **Likes** which contains 2 pointer **fromUser** and **toEstablishment**. Then you can perform a query like below:

```
var Likes = Parse.Object.extend("Likes");
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

var likesQuery = Parse.Query(Likes);
likesQuery.limit(10);
likesQuery.equalTo("fromUser",currentUser);
likesQuery.find({
       success: function(results){

       }
});
```

By long term, I mean you can utilize the pointer object in **toEstablishment** column, for example, by using [**include**](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-relational) query to get more `Establishment` data within this query.

Answer (score 0):

The two solutions mentioned above got a +1 from me because I think they're pretty good, but I believe something better can be done.

From what I see, your server doesn't need to know if a user likes an establishment or not. Only the client needs to know that. Once I know something like that, I instantly know that I'm gonna work 100% local and not store that kind of information on a server (and use up my quota of requests, data, battery, etc.).

Now I assume that you have a database in your app that updates itself with whatever is on your servers, regularly ( if you don't, I suggest you do, but that's not the point). What I would do is simply add a boolean property "isFavourite" on your establishments, and when you load them locally, check if it's local or not and put it in section 0 (or on top ) if necessary :)

That allows you to work faster, more efficiently, and still get to get your work done.

if you don't have a database you can go the less efficient way and store your favourites in the NSUserDefaults for example (an array of ID's). Since the UserDefaults are loaded at the start of your app and not when they're needed it's a bit silly, and it's not meant for that kind of storage, but it'll work just as well.

NB : The reason I strongly suggest you use a database similar to your parse database, it's so you can always load your local content when using the app (which is ridiculously simple and fast), and just update it every once in a while (when the user launches the app for example). That way, your user can read offline, load crazy fast, and you can also add "local" properties that way. For example custom settings, private establishments that the user would like to add, "notes", etc. Anything that comes up to mind :)